# How to clock-out current org-task before exit from Emacs?

Tags: org-mode, hooks, org-clock

How to clock-out current org-task before exit from Emacs? I tried

```
(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook #'org-clock-out)
```

But if there is no current active tasks, Emacs says "No active clock" instead of exit. If there is an active task, in reality clock-out does not occur and the next time when I'm trying to make org-clock-in, see the proposal to resolve the conflict.

Comment: At least for the first part you can say `(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook (lambda () (org-clock-out nil t)))`. See the doc string for `org-clock-out` for the meaning of the parameters. I don't know why it does not clock out on exit though: you might want to edebug it and see if it does get called when you kill emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
(setq org-main-file "~/orgmode/main.org")
(defun valeriy/exit ()
        (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect org-main-file)
          (save-excursion
            (org-clock-out nil t)
            (save-buffer))))
(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook #'valeriy/exit)
```

Comment: What is `treport/org-main-file`?

Comment: @Nick, this is my main and only org file with tasks. (answer updated)

Comment: OK - I see: the "treport/" was a typo.